# How to expand variable literally when calling perl from csh script?

Tags: perl, csh

Below is a `csh` script.

```
#! /bin/csh
set alpha=10\20\30;
set beta = $alpha.alpha;
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/gamma/'$beta'/' tmp;
```

The `tmp` file contains just the word `gamma`. After running `tmp.csh`, I expect `10\20\30.alpha` in tmp, but it's now `102030.alpha`.

How to preserve slashes in this situation?

Note: I wouldn't prefer changing definition of alpha variable, as it is used in the script else where where it needs to be in this format (10\20\30) only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In csh, for your alpha assignment, the backslash is being taken to mean 'a literal 2 or 3'.  In order to keep csh from doing this, the assignment needs to be enclosed in quotes.

```
#! /bin/csh
set alpha="10\20\30";
set beta = $alpha.alpha;
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/gamma/'$beta'/' tmp;
```

If in doubt, it's often helpful to 'echo' your variables out to see exactly what they contain.  I don't understand your final note, as the 'alpha' variable is not equal to 10\20\30 the way you have it originally assigned.

Comment: Hello, this works, but what if I have forward slashes in `alpha`? It gives another error then.

Comment: Did you mean to use the control characters from '\2' or '\3' or the sequence of a '\' followed by a '2' or '3'?  If it is the former, then the backslashes in alpha will need to be escaped (backslashed) themselves.  Like 'set alpha="10\\20\\30";'

Comment: I found other alternative for forward slash case. instead of 's/gamma/'$beta'/' I use 's@gamma@'$beta'@'. This way it doesn't confuse forward slashes in $beta with substitution operator delimiters. Thanks for your help anyway.